# Sticking a wooden frame to a mirror

Tags: repair, wood, mirror

I have a bathroom that needs to be gutted and re-done, but for now it has a mirror attached to the wall and someone has stuck wood around it that is supposed to look like barn wood. It is very thin and finished on one side and gives the look of a frame around it, which improves the appearance even though it doesn't go with the house.

The problem is that the top board falls off. It is obvious that a previous owner has used wood glue to try to glue it up, but it has fallen down.

When company is coming, like this weekend, we typically use high adhesive duct tape and I make a loop like we did in grade school. I do this the length of the board and stick it to the mirror. For some reason, this has worked decreasingly over the last couple of years and now it will only hold for a couple of hours. (Maybe the age of the tape? Can't figure that out.)

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can attach this thing and keep it up so that it will look presentable until we get around to remodeling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Clear silicone caulk or project adhesive (in marble-sized dabs at intervals--tape in place for 12 hours)
- Double-sided foam mounting tape
- Hot glue
- Trim nails (into framing, not just drywall)

Comment: Used the double-sided foam mounting tape. Got us through the weekend and still going. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would try command strips!! Keep the weight of the wood in mind when you choose which command strips to use as the all have different load bearing capacities. When you go to apply them follow the prep instructions on the product (very important!!).

For a more long term solution, I would try nailing the wood together to make a "real" frame and then attach a hook to it (like the ones that come attached to hanging frames) and then hang it on a nail that's hammered in above your mirror.